# List element removal occurring anyway after unsuccessful check in Python 2.7

Tags: python

I'm trying to do a system of linear congruences solver for moduli that are not coprime, which requires me to break each modulus down into its prime factorizations and compare them against each other to create a new system that is solvable. Basically what I need to do is break a number down into its prime powers (ie 36 becomes 4*9 as opposed to 2*2*3*3) and then compare it against the other modulus and remove any overlapping prime powers (ie if one number has a factor of 4 and the other has a factor of 2, we remove the factor of 2).

For some reason, when I run my code, many factors are getting removed regardless of whether they are smaller powers of another prime power in the other modulus. For example (I've included this below), when you take the moduli pair 1000142 and 1002045, the number 1002045, which has a factorization of 3 * 5 * 11 * 6073 only returns [6073] after my checks are run against it, even though the two moduli have no prime powers in common.

Does anyone know why this might be happening? I'm pretty sure my is_prime and factorize methods are correct - I've tested them extensively on ranges of numbers without issue. Why would items be getting removed from my list when the condition check fails?

Please ignore the totient and CRT stuff - it's not important.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

```
import time
from itertools import combinations
from fractions import gcd

def is_power(a, b):
    if a > b:
        a, b = b, a
    while a != b:
        if b % a != 0:
            return False
        b /= a
    return True

def factorize(n):
    primfac = []
    d = 2
    i = -1
    while d <= n:
        if n % d == 0:
            primfac.append(1)
            i += 1
        while (n % d) == 0:
            primfac[i] *= d
            n //= d
        d += 1

    return primfac

def crt(n, m):
    ans = 0
    nfactors = primeFactorizations[n]
    nfacts = nfactors
    mfactors = primeFactorizations[m]
    mfacts = mfactors
    n = n + 1000000
    m = m + 1000000

    for nfactor in nfacts:
        for mfactor in mfacts:
            else:
                if is_power(nfactor, mfactor) is True:
                    if nfactor > mfactor:
                        mfactors.remove(mfactor)
                        m //= mfactor
                    if mfactor > nfactor:
                        nfactors.remove(nfactor)
                        n //= nfactor
                    if mfactor == nfactor:
                        mfactors.remove(mfactor)
                        m // mfactor
                else:
                    pass

    print nfactors
    print mfactors

primeFactorizations = []
for i in range(1000000, 1005000):
    primeFactorizations.append(factorize(i))

for n in range(0, 4999):
    for m in range(n+1, 5000):
        crt(n, m)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the `crt` function, I see that you modify the `nfactors` and `mfactors` lists while iterating over them forwards. You are not aware that you do as you think you iterate over copies. However, `nfacts` is just another reference to the same mutable list instance as `nfactors`, the same goes for `m...`. To get real independent copies, do

```
nfacts = nfactors[:]
mfacts = mfactors[:]
```

Comment: The factorize function is meant to return the highest power of each prime. I've played with this code for a few days now, and each part behaves as intended until the main crt method is run. I will reduce the code for more clarity, though

Comment: Outside of the negative number case, in Python 2, `/=` and `//=` are equivalent, so that shouldn't matter. Using `//=` is good for forward compatibility, and ensures you get consistent behavior in Py2 even if someone imports `division` from `__future__`, but the operator is fine for Py2.

Comment: I've edited my answer now that I took a closer look at the `crt`function.

Comment: Did you even test the script? That's not the problem. Neither was my factoring method, which I stated was intentional in the second sentence of my question.

Comment: Well, if I want to test your script as you posted it, it bombs out with a syntax error from the lone `else` inside the nested loop. So no, I couldn't even test it (and it also looks like there might be something potentially important missing), but I tried to help by pointing out something that looked suspiciously wrong to me. I suggest you fix your script (and also the explanation that says the CRT wasn't important in the first place), then we'll take another look.